# How to replace variables across multiple columns using awk?

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks like this with 2060 lines with a header (column names) at the top:

```
FID     IID     late_telangiectasia_G1  late_atrophy_G1 late_atrophy_G2 late_nipple_retraction_G1       late_nipple_retraction_G2       late_oedema_G1  late_oedema_G2  late_induration_tumour_G1       late_induration_outside_G1      late_induration_G2      late_arm_lympho_G1 late_hyper_G1
1       470502  1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0      0       0       0
2       470514  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
3       470422  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1
4       470510  0       0       0       0       0       1       0       1       1       1       0       1
5       470506  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
6       471948  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0
7       469922  -9      -9      -9      -9      -9      -9      -9      -9      -9      -9      -9      -9
8       471220  0       1       1       -9      -9      0       0       1       1       1       0       0
9       470498  0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
10      471993  0       1       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
11      470414  0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0
12      470522  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
13      470345  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
14      471275  0       1       0       -9      0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0
15      471283  0       1       0       0       0       0       0       1       1       0       0       0
16      472577  0       1       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0
17      470492  0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
18      472889  0       0       0       -9      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
19      470500  0       1       0       1       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0
20      470493  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       1       0       0       0
```

I want to replace all the 0 -> 1 and the 1 -> 2  from column 3 to 12. I don't want to replace the -9.
I know for a single column the command will be:

```
awk'
{
if($3==1)$3=2
if($3==0)$3=1
}
1'file
```

Therefore, for multiple columns is there an easier way to specify a range rather than manually type every column number?

```
awk'
{
if($3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12==1)$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12=2
if($3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12==0)$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12=1
}
1'file
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You could use a loop and change the field values accessing the field value using `$i`

```
awk '
{
  for(i=3; i<=12; i++) {
    if ($i==1 || $i==0) $i++
  }
}1
' file | column -t
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility if you want to change almost all of your fields (as in your case) is to just save the ones you don't want to change and then change everything else:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{hd=$1 FS $2; tl=$13 FS $14; $1=$2=$13=$14=""; gsub(1,2); gsub(0,1); $0=hd $0 tl} 1' file
FID     IID     late_telangiectasia_G1  late_atrophy_G1 late_atrophy_G2 late_nipple_retraction_G1       late_nipple_retraction_G2       late_oedema_G1  late_oedema_G2  late_induration_tumour_G1       late_induration_outside_G1      late_induration_G2      late_arm_lympho_G1 late_hyper_G1
1 470502  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  0 0
2 470514  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  0 0
3 470422  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  0 1
4 470510  1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2  0 1
5 470506  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  0 0
6 471948  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1  0 0
7 469922  -9 -9 -9 -9 -9 -9 -9 -9 -9 -9  -9 -9
8 471220  1 2 2 -9 -9 1 1 2 2 2  0 0
9 470498  1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  0 0
10 471993  1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  0 0
11 470414  1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1  0 0
12 470522  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  0 0
13 470345  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  0 0
14 471275  1 2 1 -9 1 1 1 2 1 1  0 0
15 471283  1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1  0 0
16 472577  1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1  0 0
17 470492  1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  0 0
18 472889  1 1 1 -9 1 1 1 1 1 1  0 0
19 470500  1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1  0 0
20 470493  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1  0 0
```

pipe it to `column -t` for alignment if you like.

Or using GNU awk for the 3rg arg to match() and retaining white space:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{ match($0,/((\S+\s+){2})((\S+\s+){9}\S+)(.*)/,a); gsub(1,2,a[3]); gsub(0,1,a[3]); $0=a[1] a[3] a[5] } 1' file
FID     IID     late_telangiectasia_G1  late_atrophy_G1 late_atrophy_G2 late_nipple_retraction_G1       late_nipple_retraction_G2       late_oedema_G1  late_oedema_G2  late_induration_tumour_G1       late_induration_outside_G1      late_induration_G2      late_arm_lympho_G1 late_hyper_G1
1       470502  2       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1      1       0       0
2       470514  1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       0       0
3       470422  1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       0       1
4       470510  1       1       1       1       1       2       1       2       2       2       0       1
5       470506  1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       0       0
6       471948  1       1       1       1       1       1       1       2       1       1       0       0
7       469922  -9      -9      -9      -9      -9      -9      -9      -9      -9      -9      -9      -9
8       471220  1       2       2       -9      -9      1       1       2       2       2       0       0
9       470498  1       2       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       0       0
10      471993  1       2       2       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       0       0
11      470414  1       2       1       1       1       1       1       1       2       1       0       0
12      470522  1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       0       0
13      470345  1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       0       0
14      471275  1       2       1       -9      1       1       1       2       1       1       0       0
15      471283  1       2       1       1       1       1       1       2       2       1       0       0
16      472577  1       2       1       1       1       1       1       2       1       1       0       0
17      470492  1       2       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       0       0
18      472889  1       1       1       -9      1       1       1       1       1       1       0       0
19      470500  1       2       1       2       1       1       1       1       2       1       0       0
20      470493  1       1       1       1       1       1       1       2       2       1       0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell if that is space delimited or tab delimited?

Here is a ruby that will deal with either space or tab delimited fields and will convert the result to tab delimited.

Note: Ruby arrays are zero based, so fields 1,2 are `[0..1]` and fields 3-12 are `[2..11]`

```
ruby -r csv -e 'options={:col_sep=>"\t", :converters=>:all, :headers=>true}
data=CSV.parse($<.read.gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/,"\t"), **options)
data.each_with_index{
  |r,i| data[i]=r[0..1]+r[2..11].map{|e| (e==1 || e==0) ? e+1 : e}+r[12..]}
puts data.to_csv(**options)
' file
```

Prints:

```
FID IID late_telangiectasia_G1  late_atrophy_G1 late_atrophy_G2 late_nipple_retraction_G1   late_nipple_retraction_G2   late_oedema_G1  late_oedema_G2  late_induration_tumour_G1   late_induration_outside_G1  late_induration_G2  late_arm_lympho_G1  late_hyper_G1
1   470502  2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
2   470514  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
3   470422  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1
4   470510  1   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   2   2   0   1
5   470506  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
6   471948  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   0   0
7   469922  -9  -9  -9  -9  -9  -9  -9  -9  -9  -9  -9  -9
8   471220  1   2   2   -9  -9  1   1   2   2   2   0   0
9   470498  1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
10  471993  1   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
11  470414  1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   0   0
12  470522  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
13  470345  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
14  471275  1   2   1   -9  1   1   1   2   1   1   0   0
15  471283  1   2   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   1   0   0
16  472577  1   2   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   0   0
17  470492  1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
18  472889  1   1   1   -9  1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
19  470500  1   2   1   2   1   1   1   1   2   1   0   0
20  470493  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   1   0   0
```

With `awk` you can do:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 'FNR>1{for(i=3;i<=12;i++)if ($i~"^[10]$")$i=$i+1} $1=$1' file   

# same output
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '++c > 2 && /^(0|1)$/ { ++$0 }
        { printf "%s", $0 RT } RT ~ /\n/ { c = 0 }' file
```